# Where can I find more information about "token-2022" and how it relates to the current token program?

Tags: spl-token, token, token-2022, documentation

Where can I read about the need for token-2022, it's overall design, expected benefits, and how it relates to the current token program?

I've been through the following resources:

- [current token program docs](https://spl.solana.com/token) (token-2022 not mentioned)
- [repo-level project board](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/projects/1)
- [org-level project board](https://github.com/orgs/solana-labs/projects/4)
- [token-2022 release notes](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/releases?q=SPL+Token+2022&expanded=true)
- [token-2022 source code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program-2022/src)

The latter two provide some hints about introduced functionality and feature set but I'm having difficulty finding any discussion of the *genesis* of the token-2022 program. Ideally there's a proposal document somewhere that I'm just unable to find. Maybe it explains what's driving this development? I'm also interested in reading how it's expected to relate to the existing token program. Is it a drop-in replacement with extended capabilities? Will token accounts need maintenance/upgrades to support token-2022? etc.

A centralized starting point that captures the overall vision would be really helpful. Hopefully one that lays out the motivations and designs for each component of the new feature set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More formal docs are [in the works](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/3384).  Keep an eye on https://spl.solana.com