# What is the closing mint in the Token-2022 program?

Tags: token-2022

I noticed the new Token-2022 program appear recently and I was wondering if anyone knows what the "closing mint" will do in the list of new features:

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022

(I reviewed the following question, but it is not focused and is not about the closing mint:
[Where can I find more information about "token-2022" and how it relates to the current token program?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/864/where-can-i-find-more-information-about-token-2022-and-how-it-relates-to-the-c))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `closing mint` refers to the added functionality to assign a `MintCloseAuthority`. This authority will be able to *close* the mint, which will disable any further minting for the respective token.

This is new flexibility added withe the Token-2022 program. With the old TokenProgram, we had a MintAuthority and UpdateAuthority, but no separate MintCloseAuthority.

See a short section of the source code:

```
        extension::{
            confidential_transfer::{ConfidentialTransferAccount, ConfidentialTransferMint},
            default_account_state::DefaultAccountState,
            immutable_owner::ImmutableOwner,
            interest_bearing_mint::InterestBearingConfig,
            memo_transfer::MemoTransfer,
            mint_close_authority::MintCloseAuthority,
            non_transferable::NonTransferable,
            transfer_fee::{TransferFeeAmount, TransferFeeConfig},
        },
```

or check it out yourself on [github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022/src/extension/mod.rs)

Comment: How is having a ```MintCloseAuthority``` different from just doing this: ```spl-token authorize TOKEN_ID mint --disable``` ?

Comment: `spl-token authorize TOKEN_ID mint --disable` will close the mint. The `MintCloseAuthority` feature will allow you to set an address that is ALLOWED to close the mint. Before the MintCloseAuthority feature, only the one that has MintAuthority can close the mint. With the new feature, you can delegate that authority to a different user/address. In short: Closing the mint has always been possible, but the new feature is the ability to assign an **authority** only for closing the mint.